# "No signal detected" after upgrading case and PSU

Tags: boot, bios, power-supply, amd-radeon

I have strange and randomly ocurring problem. Very often my PC boots without any signal to monitor (I can toggle num/caps lock) but cannot get anything to display. Monitor says no signal.

This started happening after I bought new case with new PSU (Fortron Hyper M 500W). Some days before that I also bought MSI RX 480 Gaming X to replace my old reference Radeon HD 7950. But everything worked fine until changing the case and PSU.

Now I also tried HD 7950 again but PC does not boot with it at all. I believe 500W PSU should be enough.

Rest of my PC:
Intel Core i7-3770K (TDP 77W)
MoBo: Pegatron 2AD5 (it was HP branded Pavillion PC)
RAM: 4x4GB
Primary SSD and secondary HDD
+ one DVD-RW

I tried to find BIOS update but couldn't. I also found this: "The fix was to change the PCI ROM Priority setting from "EFI Compatability ROM" to "Legacy ROM" on the "Boot" tab of the BIOS." but I don't have this option.

Some Radeon RX cards have switch on them to fix this, but mine unfortunately does not.

So currently my PC boots OK 1 in 5 tries, otherwise black screen.

EDIT: Tried my old PSU with the same result. Again black screen.

Comment: Have you tried using the old PSU to see if this has any bearing? If you are careful, you can swap out all the connections without having to mount the old PSU in the case. Keep cats and babies away while it is on of course

Comment: @Yorik not yet, I would like to believe that at least new PSU is working properly but I'll try that just to be sure.

Comment: Try old PSU, I had a new PSU be junk out of the box before.  It happens.

Comment: @Yorik just tried the old PSU with the same non-working result. So that leaves motherboard, but it all worked fine just before the case/PSU upgrade :/

Comment: According to the HP site, it looks like there may be a "POST delay" option under advanced/power-on options. Try setting this to 30 seconds and see if this has an affect.

Comment: @Yorik thanks, so far encouraging results. Do you know why this seems to solve the problem?

Comment: Not really sure, but it may just be too quick (firmware bug?) for the GPU to initialize. If it has an mainboard DVI/VGA/HDMIand the CPU supports it, the board may fall back to that too quickly? Try reducing the POST delay as low as it can go so you boot quicker. you can post and accept your own answe if you feel it is resolved.

Comment: @Yorik so I got another black screen with the delay, overall it seems like it helped a bit but it may very well be just random. I'll probably try to buy used motherboard..